# SQLite data not persisting

Tags: android

Hi I am working on the Udacity Popular movies project. I have to store the movies user chooses in a content provider as his favorites. I have created a content provider and I am fetching the data from it using a cursor loader and displaying it a recycler view when the user chooses the favorites option. My issue is that the data is not being persisted in my app. After I remove the app from my stack and reopen the app the favorites screen is empty. What am I doing wrong?

This is my Main Activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomCursorAdapter.CustomCursorAdapterOnClickHandler,ImagesAdapter.ImagesAdapterOnClickHandler,LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {



      private final String POPULAR_WEBSITE = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?API_KEY";
        private final String RATED_WEBSITE = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?API_KEY";
      //  private final String RATED_WEBSITE = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?API_KEY";

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ImagesAdapter adapter;
    TextView errorTextView ;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Bundle savedState = null;

    ArrayList<MoviesClass> moviesClassList = new ArrayList<>();
    final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

CustomCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        errorTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error_message);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);



getLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,this);


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
simpleCursorAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this,null,this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new ImagesAdapter(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (NetworkUtility.isOnline()) {

                        loadData(POPULAR_WEBSITE);

                    } else {

                       // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);

                        // Setting Dialog Title
                        alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.no_internet_connection);

                        // Setting Dialog Message
                        alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.exit);



                        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.positive_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                                // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.exit_activity, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

                        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.negative_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.connection_check, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                dialog.cancel();
                           MainActivity.this.recreate();
                            }
                        });

                        // Showing Alert Message
                        alertDialog.show();

                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }


            }


    });
    }

    private void loadData(String data) {

        showDataView();
        new DownloadTask().execute(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void mClick(int position) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MovieDetails.class);
        MoviesClass currentMovie = moviesClassList.get(position);
        intent.putExtra("current movie", currentMovie);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void showDataView() {

        errorTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void showError() {

        errorTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


    @Override
    public CursorLoader onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);

        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Cursor o) {

     //   simpleCursorAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this,o,this);
simpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(o);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {


        simpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void click(int position) {

    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList<String>> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> s) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            showDataView();
            adapter.setAdapterData(s);
            //  onSaveInstanceState(savedState);

        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String response = null;
            ArrayList<String> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> uriList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (strings.length == 0)
                return null;





                    try {
                        response = NetworkUtility.makeHttpRequest(strings[0]);
                        if (response == null)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.error_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        moviesClassList = ParseData.getMoviesObject(response);
                        for(int i =0; i< moviesClassList.size();i++)
                            Log.i(TAG, moviesClassList.get(0).getmId());
                        MoviesClass moviesClass = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < moviesClassList.size(); i++) {



                            moviesClass = moviesClassList.get(i);
Log.i("movie name is",moviesClass.getmTitle());
                            imagesList.add(moviesClass.getmPosterPath());

                            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
                            builder.scheme("http")
                                    .appendEncodedPath("/image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185")
                                    .appendEncodedPath(imagesList.get(i)).build();
                            uriList.add(builder.toString());

                        }


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return uriList;







        }

    }




    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.popular_sort:
                loadData(POPULAR_WEBSITE);
                return true;
            case R.id.rated_sort:
                loadData(RATED_WEBSITE);
                return true;
            case R.id.fav_sort:
/*try {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Log.i("url is ", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("url")));
        list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("url")));
    }

}finally {
    cursor.close();
}*/

recyclerView.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
simpleCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                return true;
            default:
                return false;


        }

    }
```

This my content provider class ;

```
public class FavouritesContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    public static final int MOVIES = 100;
    public static final int  MOVIE_ID = 101;
    private MovieDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Context context = getContext();
        dbOpenHelper = new MovieDbOpenHelper(context,null,null,1);
        return true;
    }

    public UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

    private UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {

        UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(FavouritesContractClass.AUTHORITY,FavouritesContractClass.PATH_FAVOURITES,MOVIES);
        uriMatcher.addURI(FavouritesContractClass.AUTHORITY,FavouritesContractClass.PATH_FAVOURITES + "/#",MOVIE_ID);

return uriMatcher;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] strings, @Nullable String s, @Nullable String[] strings1, @Nullable String s1) {

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        switch (match) {

            case MOVIES:
                cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.TABLE_NAME, strings, s, strings1, null, null, s1);

                break;

            case MOVIE_ID:

                cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.TABLE_NAME, strings, s, strings1, null, null, s1);

                break;

            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri:" + uri);

        }

        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);
        return cursor;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);

        switch (match) {
            case MOVIES:
                // directory
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir" + "/" + FavouritesContractClass.AUTHORITY + "/" + FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.CONTENT_URI;
            case MOVIE_ID:
                // single item type
                return "vnd.android.cursor.item" + "/" + FavouritesContractClass.AUTHORITY + "/" + FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.CONTENT_URI;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues contentValues) {

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
Uri returnUri = null;
        switch (match) {
            case MOVIES:
                long id = sqLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                if (id > 0)
                    returnUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.CONTENT_URI, id);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri" + uri);
        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
        return returnUri;


        }



    @Override
    public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String s, @Nullable String[] strings) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues contentValues, @Nullable String s, @Nullable String[] strings) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is the movie details class:

```
public class MovieDetails extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public final String trailerBaseUri = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";
    String movieId;
    Uri movieFinalUri, movieReviewUri;
    ArrayList<MovieTrailerClass> movieTrailersList;
    String movieReviewsList;
    Uri.Builder builder;
    MoviesClass currentMovie;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_details);
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_tv);
        TextView synopsis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.synopsis_tv);
        TextView userRating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating_tv);
        TextView date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_tv);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.poster_thumbnail);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        ImageView trailer1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trailer1);
        ImageView trailer2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trailer2);

        trailer1.setOnClickListener(this);
        trailer2.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (intent.hasExtra("current movie")) {


            currentMovie = intent.getParcelableExtra("current movie");

            builder = new Uri.Builder();
            builder.scheme("http")
                    .appendEncodedPath("/image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185")
                    .appendEncodedPath(currentMovie.getmPosterPath()).build();

            movieId = currentMovie.getmId();

            title.setText(currentMovie.getmTitle());
            synopsis.setText(currentMovie.getmSynopsis());

            userRating.setText(currentMovie.getmRating() + "/10");

            date.setText(currentMovie.getmReleaseDate());

            movieFinalUri = Uri.parse(trailerBaseUri).buildUpon().appendPath(movieId).appendPath("videos").appendQueryParameter("api_key", "ebd331efd1f9bec67a9aa215b256ebe1")
                    .appendQueryParameter("language", "en").build();

            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(builder.toString())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.popcorn_placeholder)
                    .error(R.drawable.error)
                    .resize(800, 1000)
                    .into(imageView);

            movieTrailersList = new ArrayList<>();
            DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
            task.execute(movieFinalUri.toString());


            movieReviewUri = Uri.parse(trailerBaseUri).buildUpon().appendPath(movieId).appendPath("reviews").appendQueryParameter("api_key", "ebd331efd1f9bec67a9aa215b256ebe1")
                    .appendQueryParameter("language", "en").build();
            ReviewDownloadTask task1 = new ReviewDownloadTask();
            task1.execute(movieReviewUri.toString());


            //  String movieReviewsExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("movieReviewList");


        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.trailer1:

                openTrailer(movieTrailersList.get(0).getKey());
                break;

            case R.id.rating_tv:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MovieDetails.this, ReviewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("movieReviewList", movieReviewsList);
                startActivity(intent);
           /* case R.id.trailer3:

                openTrailer(movieTrailersList.get(2).getKey());
                break;*/

        }
    }

    public void openTrailer(String key) {


        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?").buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("v", key).build();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    public void openReview(String url) {


        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null) {
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to find browser to launch movie trailer!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    public void markAsFavourite(View view) {


        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.MOVIE_URL, builder.toString());
        contentValues.put(FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.MOVIE_ID, movieId);

        /*if(checkAlreadyExist()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {*/

            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

            if (uri != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.movie_saved_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("insert successsful", uri.toString());
            } else
                Log.i("insert not successsful", "suc");

    }

    class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<MovieTrailerClass>> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<MovieTrailerClass> doInBackground(String... strings) {


            try {

                String response = NetworkUtility.makeHttpRequest(movieFinalUri.toString());
                if (response != null) {
                    JSONObject baseObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray resObject = baseObj.getJSONArray("results");


                    Gson gson = new Gson();

                    movieTrailersList = gson.fromJson(resObject.toString(), new TypeToken<List<MovieTrailerClass>>() {
                    }.getType());

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(MovieDetails.this, R.string.error_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return movieTrailersList;

        }

    }

    public class ReviewDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String response = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ArrayList<MovieReviewResults> movieReviewResults = gson.fromJson(movieReviewsList, new TypeToken<List<MovieReviewResults>>() {
            }.getType());


            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

            for (MovieReviewResults movieReviewObject : movieReviewResults) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

                textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                textView.setGravity((Gravity.CENTER));
                linearLayout.addView(textView);
                textView.setText(movieReviewObject.getContent());


                TextView textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                textView1.setGravity((Gravity.CENTER));
                textView1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                linearLayout.addView(textView1);
                textView1.setText(movieReviewObject.getAuthor());
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


            try {
                response = NetworkUtility.makeHttpRequest(strings[0]);
                if (response != null) {
                    JSONObject baseObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray resObject = baseObj.getJSONArray("results");
                    movieReviewsList = resObject.toString();


                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(MovieDetails.this, R.string.error_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return movieReviewsList;

        }
    }


    public boolean checkAlreadyExist()
    {

        String query =  "SELECT " + FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.MOVIE_ID + " FROM " + FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.MOVIE_ID + " = " + movieId;;

        MovieDbOpenHelper  dbOpenHelper = new MovieDbOpenHelper(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);


        SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Log.i(" ai mger","here");
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            Log.i("fpund","funf");
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try calling `beginTransaction` before inserting/updating/deleting, `setTransactionSuccessful` when you want the changes to be committed and `endTransaction` to commit the changes. Please see code below (NOTE: I didn't test this code as I'm writing this on a tablet)

You should also take a look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()) for more information.

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues contentValues) {

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Uri returnUri = null;
        switch (match) {
            case MOVIES:
                sqLiteDatabase.beginTransaction();

                try {
                    long id = sqLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                    if (id > 0)
                        returnUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(FavouritesContractClass.FavouriteMovies.CONTENT_URI, id);
                    sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
                } finally {
                    sqLiteDatabase.endTransaction();
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri" + uri);
        }

        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
        return returnUri;


    }
```